# $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm asked to identify if the following is a vector space and if it is not I need to identify the axiom that it fails to satisfy:

> $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I don't think it is a vector space because the $1$ would cause it to fail in both closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Am I correct?

Comment: Is the zero matrix in there?

Comment: A sum of any two matrices in the set will give you a "2" in the lower-right entry; a non-zero scalar multiple  other than 1 of any member of the set leaves something other than "1" in that entry.  So you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a vector space, the zero matrix fails to be in there.

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer?

Comment: One of the definition of a vector space is that the $0$ vector is in the vector space. Since 1 is a fixed value, you'll never get the zero matrix.

Comment: I see, and I was going to say you could use the scalar $0$ to get rid of the $1$, but that is not a legal matrix operation.

Comment: It's also true that it fails the closure under addition and scalar multiplication axiom as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.